# WPF ContextMenu / MenuItem - Hide vertical Separator

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a context menu and inside are two menu items. To remove the check mark and icon for the menu items i've created a style which is working great. However i've noticed that in the background there is a vertical separator which i can't get rid of using style for context menu. Any help?